# vb.net mdi child is hidden behind MDI Parent Panels

Tags: vb.net, winforms, mdi, mdichild, mdiparent

I am planning to have a vb.net windows form applocation that has a main mdi ( contains menu strip + panels  all over the mdi )
the problems is when a child form is shown  , and when minimizing the child form it disappears behind the main mdi.

any ideas how to solve this without changing the size of the child form
[MDI Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ok0J7.png)

Comment: "Panels all over MdiParent" -> doesn't make sense, otherwise your MdiChild will not be shown. Please add a bit more description about the layout and tell how you show the mdi child.

Comment: For an MdiParent to work correctly, all Panels in the "client' area must be DOCKED to the sides. This will properly change the "child" area and allow the children to be visible in whatever area is left behind after the panels have been docked. It's not clear if you are properly displaying your "child" forms as correct MdiChildren. I recommend you post your code that displays the children so we can verify that portion...

Comment: Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        A_Login.MdiParent = Me
        A_Login.Show()


    End Sub

Comment: I tried to resize Panels in the main mdi in height , to make a room for the child to be minimized , it went ok , but still when the child is shown it appears behind the main mdi Panels

Comment: It's not clear if you actually DOCKED the panels. Your comment simply says you changed their height. Again, all panels in the normal mdi child client area must be DOCKED to the sides.

Comment: my panels are docked to the sides and i deleted my middle panel , but still the side panels overlap the child form